# How to make timeseries from pandas dataframe in Altair

Tags: pandas, altair

I've got a dataset from here.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/l7toin3wj6s6iwd3s6r8y/local_obesity.csv?rlkey=lk8ipdlhgdfijscq429pksktk&dl=0

I wanted to create an interactive visualisation using Altair which works, but also doesn't.

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/elksie5000/files/home/elksie5000/local_obesity.html

The West Midlands selection includes London which isn't right. My code  so far is:

```
# Create dropdown selections
result_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=melted_df['result'].unique().tolist(), name="Local authority: ")

result_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['result'], bind=result_dropdown, name='Area')

variable_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=melted_df['variable'].unique().tolist(), name="Category: ")
variable_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['variable'], bind=variable_dropdown, name='Variable')
# Sort the data by 'year' before plotting
sorted_data = melted_df.sort_values(by='year')


# Create the updated Altair plot
chart = alt.Chart(sorted_data).mark_line(size=10).encode(
    x='year:O',
    y=alt.Y('mean(value):Q', title='Selected Value'),
    color='region:N',
    tooltip=["region","value", "year"]
).add_selection(
    result_selection
).transform_filter(
    result_selection
).add_selection(
    variable_selection
).transform_filter(
    variable_selection
).properties(width=400)

chart
```

Why is it that the selection on this plot filters correctly, although for a line plot I would expect to see the trend upwards?

[image]